# Can I use a single driver to run parallely multiple tests in Selenium (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

With the way my project is structured, it was made with all functions calling one static driver, since I didn't expect I'd need to do many tests simultaneously. Now I'm using TestNG and, right now it's opening up multiple tests and doing both test actions in one of the windows, effectively crashing the test.

This happens because all the basic functions that I've made (such as clickbutton, login user, etc) call a static driver from a class I've named DriverManager. And to change that I'd have to basically refactor the entire code, putting a driver as an entry object to most functions I've made.

Is there any way I can do the tests parallelly using TestNG with only one driver?

Comment: not familiar with TestNG, but you'll need one driver instance per browser/thread.  You can use one driver for multiple tabs, but it wouldn't be parallel.  There is one thing that can be done parallel... it's the new "ticks" for use with actions:  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#ticks

Answer (score -1):

```
Yes you can do it ,

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Parallel"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->



This is XML file 

Parallel is class name 

You can do parallel by **method,tests,classes and instances** 


following code for run test parallel

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Parallel {


   WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\SeleniumParallelTestingFinal\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Testing");

    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\SeleniumParallelTestingFinal\\src\\main\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Testing");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("WELCOME TO WORLD JESUS");



    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. You've got one `Driver` per test, which is exactly what OP doesn't have (and apparently can't do without some serious refactoring).